# is there any way to read one number from the anonymous pipe in two different processes?

Tags: c++, process, pipe

I have one anonymous pipe and two child processes. I write one number in the pipe and now i have to read it in both processes. is there any way?

I tried to GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), also I tried to use cin.peek but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't tell us which kind of anonymous pipes you're dealing with. However, since pipe is a UNIX concept in its core, I'll assume you're referring to POSIX pipes.

These don't support multi-reader access. A read access necessarily consumes the read bytes from the underlying buffer.

So what you want is impossible, kind of by design.

However, reading that you have two *child* processes, it would seem sensible to assume you could use shared memory for the actual data exchange, and some other means for synchronization of access.

Comment: The same is true for pipes on Windows, too.

Comment: i use windows. i assume i need to use two different pipes?

Comment: @ВладСолодов Remy already answered that directly above your comment.